# How often a value below 50 occurs?

Tags: excel

I've got a .xlsx file I'm working on, and there's one last thing I'm trying to achieve. I have a column with different numbers down the rows which have 6 blank rows between each of them. So, they are each separated from each other by six blank rows.

Like this:

```
100





60





33

etc.
```

---

They are separated into weeks, so that's why there's six blanks in between each of them. The number is on the seventh day of each week.

What I'm trying to do is, in the next column over, I want to display how often a value below 50 occurs on average. Like X every X weeks, or days.

I've looked all over the place, but it seems nobody else has asked this question.

---

**EDIT:**

The exact result I want to achieve is displaying on average how many weeks (values) are there before a number below 50 shows up. I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: I suppose what I need to display is something like, on average, how many weeks or days are there before a number below 50 comes up.

Comment: At first, think of what exact result you need. You got values for each week. So You can consider "in 4 weeks, how often is the value under 50"?

Comment: Okay, the exact result I want to achieve is displaying on average how many weeks (values) are there before a number below 50 shows up. I have no idea how to do this. I've looked everywhere, but found nothing.

Comment: You might want to combine `Count` with `Index` `Match`. Using `Match` to determine the first value < 50, and `Index` to determine the row number this happens at. Use said row number as argument in your `Count` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try something like:

```
=COUNT(A:A)/COUNTIF(A:A,"<50")
```

For your sample should return `3` (ie once every 3 weeks).

Comment: Thanks. So, this is the average amount of 50+ numbers in a row before a -50 shows up?

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be what I was trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

@Arnie:

Let's arrange a sheet with numbers from 1 to 100 in its first column; this seems what your data will look like firsthand.

In a separate cell, you can use the counting functions in Excel to tell you, inside a given range of cells:

- how many cells are not empty?
- how many cells have a value over 45?, under 50?, equal to 60?

The first function will give you the size of your data sample. Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rSelector), where rSelector is a range pointed at your set of cells containing the data sample, will give you how many actual samples your base does have.

The other function is Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rSelector,expression), where expression will contain the condition to be met by the cells contents in order to be useful for the calculations.

If you want to know how many times a figure lower than 50 (whatever it means) appears on your weekly data, you just have to use "<50" or "<=50" for the CountIf expression; you're the one to decide if the threshold is to be included ("<=") or not ("<") in the calculations.

Dividing the latter by the former you'll get the amount of "less than 50" cases per week, which Excel can show as a percentage for you. If you divide the total number of weeks by the amount of "less than 50", you'll get an average of how many weeks must pass before a figure like that may appear on your data.

I hope this helps you.

**EDIT:**

Should spatial/temporal information be of interest for the record, let's add some provisions or additional columns.

First of all, for the sake of flexibility, let's put the threshold value on a given cell and refer to it as locked row and column: $G$3.

Let's keep an empty row on top of the actual data.

Let's set B:B cells equal to:

```
=IF(A2<=$G$3;1;0)
```

this way, cells Bx will show a value of 1 whenever cell Ax is smaller than $G$3.
Let's set C:C cells equal to:

```
=IF(B2=1;0;C1+1)
```

this way, C column will show how many weeks have passed since the last lower_than_threshold week.
Let's set D:D cells equal to:

```
=IF(C3=0;C2;0)
```

this way, column D will show just the number of weeks before we register a value lower_than_threshold. You can average those values as well, in case it is of any interest for you.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like it might work. I'll try this pnuts suggestion turns out to be not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I fully agree with pnuts: By resorting to average calculations, you lose some (maybe) important spatial/temporal information.